# unable to open table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

when I try open table in sql server management studio I receive the message

```
Timeout Expired
```

Then when I try and rename the table I get

```
Rename Failed Lock Request Time out Expired
```

Noting that it just contain one row with primary key field, datetime field and varbinary(max) field. and the other tables are working just fine. this occures once in a while.
so what should i do to resoulve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean open? Design window or query?

Check locks on your server first:

```
exec sp_lock
```

To set database singleuser you can do this:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE db SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
USE db;
GO
--DO YOUR WORK HERE
GO
ALTER DATABASE db SET MULTI_USER;
```

Some helpful stored procedures and dynamic views:

```
select DB_NAME(1)
select OBJECT_NAME(1131151075,1)

exec sp_lock
-- locks for sesion 51
exec sp_lock 51

select DB_NAME(dbid)
select OBJECT_NAME(ObjId,dbid)

select * from sys.dm_tran_locks

select * from sys.dm_exec_connections
select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions
select * from sys.dm_tran_active_transactions
select * from sys.dm_tran_database_transactions
```

You can also watch activity monitor and kill sesion that create lock.
There is more information about that:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx

Comment: i mean query; i am unable to do select commands and the end users application is not working, so i want to release the lock; also what do you mean by Do YOUR WORK HERE, is it my select command, if yes, then i am just trying to do the select because the end users applicatoin is not working.

Comment: Qyery above means: Rollback any transaction on that database and set database in a SINGLE_USER mode. And then you don't have to worry about concurency. In commented place you can insert your query. But it is only workaround for now and sigle user(admin). I suggest to look at activity monitor and sp_lock procedure results to find out where is the problem and who's locked this table.

Comment: i got the following: 54   1   1131151075  0  TAB  IS  GRANT, what should i do to release the table, so the end users can work again. and how can i know the cause, thanx

Comment: This is default lock on master database. I'll post you above some helpful sp to find out where is the problem

Comment: OK, i know it is the master database, but suppose it is on another database named xDB and on a table named ytable, how can i release the lock? because i detached the database and attached it again so  there is no lock now. but i am asking for future.

Comment: Force kill or rollback immediate. The problem is not how to release lock but how to avoid. You need to look at your queries and find where you can give for example NOLOCK. But if you want to change definition of table you have to use rollback immediate and single user.

Comment: OK, thanx, but i am just calling a stored procedure to retrieve this single row from my desktop application and no inserts, no updates happens to this table, so should i add NOLOCK to my stored procedure to prevent this happening again? thanx again.

Comment: No. Single query shouldn't be problem here. Anyway try to reproduce lock and do some more research with this sp & dv to find source of the problem. thx

Comment: this is a single query in SP BUT it is used by arround 500 user within 2 hours through a web service function, how would i know the cause, any comments. thanx again.